# Sequence of 2-color combinations

Tags: permutations, generating-functions

I'm crafting flowers made of two colors, a petal color and a center color. I have 5 colors total: yellow, green, pink, orange, and blue.

I have already made flowers with these color combinations:

1. Pink petals, yellow center
2. Yellow petals, green center
3. Green petals, orange center
4. Orange petals, blue center

I would like to create flowers with all possible combinations* of two distinct colors, but there are a few conditions for the sequence.

- The center color of the previous flower becomes the petal color of the next one.
- The same color should never be used 3 times in a row.
- As much as possible, I would like to maintain a consistent gap between when each color appears.

Please help me find the best sequence of flowers that picks up where I left off above! If you do, my math PhD friends will be so annoyed someone else did it first!

*All possible combinations means a pink petal, yellow center flower and a yellow petal, pink center flower are distinct.

Comment: Label the colors 1,2,3,4,5.  Use clock arithmetic, so that (for example) 4 + 2 = 1, 5 + 1 = 1.  Let an r-cycle denote pairs, x,y where y = x+r : r in {1,2,3,4}.  Initially, I considered starting with a 1-cycle, where the first pair was (1,5) and the last was (5,1), and then going to a 2-cycle, and then a 3-cycle, and then a 4-cycle.  ...see next comment

Comment: I found that the end of the 2-cycle was (4,1), and then the next two pairs in the 3-cycle would be (1,4), (4,2).  This would violate the constraint that you can not use color 4, three times in a row.  I think that the r-cycle is the right approach, but you will need to shuffle the r-cycles, since (as mentioned) 1-cycle, then 2-cycle, then 3-cycle, is no good.